# SQL Developer is too slow. What else can i use?

Tags: oracle

This program is SLOW LIKE HELL, and i'm using windows.
I only need to make queries and navigate into databases/procedures/sequences, what else i can use ?

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?  What version of the JVM?  What, exactly, is slow?  And what constitutes "slow"?  For example, using SQL Developer 3.1 using a Java 1.7 JVM, expanding the `Packages` node of the navigator populates in a couple of seconds for me in a schema with a few dozen packages.

Comment: JVM 1.60, SQL Developer 3.0, i'll try to update it!

Comment: This is clearly a bad question for this site, but +1 because I totally understand how you feel.

Comment: I disagree whether or not this is a bad question. Maybe someone simply says: Oh wait, in file blah adjust JVM settings to bloeh and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could find an answer easily ...

Here is a link for you : [Alternative to Oracle SQL Developer](http://alternativeto.net/software/oracle-sql-developer/)

Comment: This is a big list. can you tell me a free and fast one ?

Comment: You just have to select Free and Open Source at the top of the list ... try with the one with higher likes or try to find comments about it by typing the name on Google ... you will find more information by this way than i could give you by typing some lines. It depends of what you want in this program.